# Split image path in javascript from first slash

Tags: javascript

I have the following path :

```
/data/2/444/test.text
```

or (without a slash at the start of the path)
    data/2/444/test.text

I would like to return in JS the following result :

```
   "/2/444/test.text"
```

I tried with  the following: but I managed only to get the base name

```
new String(str).substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: How generic should it be? Is the path always starting with `/data`/`data`?

Comment: Sometimes it's from the first slash, but sometimes (as you describe this) it's starting from the second slash. What would determine starting from the first or second?

Comment: How about `str.split('/data')[1]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to remove the first directory in the path.

```
str.replace(/^\/?[^/]+\//, '/')
```

- `^\/?` Optional slash at the beginning of string.
- `[^/]+\//` match any non slash character until it encounter a slash

```js
const input = ['/data/2/444/test.text', 'data/2/444/test.text', 'file.txt'];

const output = input.map(str => str.replace(/^\/?[^/]+\//, '/'))
 
console.log(output);
```

If you only want to replace `/data` from the beginning you can use:

```
^\/?data\/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it without regexes and using `slice` and `indexOf`:

```js
const getPath=path=>path.slice(path.indexOf('/',path[0]==="/"?1:0)-path.length);

console.log(getPath('/data/2/444/test.text'));
console.log(getPath('data/2/444/test.text'));
```

This checks if the first char is a `/` or not, and adjusts the `indexOf` accordingly to match either the second or first `/`. Also note how the subtraction gives a negative value, which gets the intended characters from the end, up to the `/`.

Of course you can do still do it with `substring`, as you were attempting, but with `indexOf` instead of `lastIndexOf`, because you want the 1st or 2nd `/` not the last one:

```js
const getPath=path=>path.substring(path.indexOf('/',path[0]==="/"?1:0),path.length);

console.log(getPath('/data/2/444/test.text'));
console.log(getPath('data/2/444/test.text'));
```

It's worth mentioning that these may not be as robust as a regex, but are simple enough, and may fit your needs, depending on how the data can vary.

Answer (score 1):

`lastIndexOf` finds the last occurrence of a string within a string. When you use `substring(x)` on a string `y`, it will return the characters of `y` starting at `x`. So using `lastIndexOf` in this use case isn't what you want. You can achieve what you want by using `indexOf` (finding the first occurrence of a string within a string). 
To account for the different formats of your input string (i.e. `/data` and `data`), you can just test for that:

```
function getPathWithoutData(str) {
    var strWithoutSlash = str[0] === '/' ? str.substring(1) : str;
    return strWithoutSlash.substring(strWithoutSlash.indexOf('/'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and pass it a regex.

```js
const paths = [
  "/data/path/one",
  "data/path/two"
];
const modifyPath = p => {
  const [fallback, newPath] = p.split(/\/?data/);
  return newPath || fallback;
}
console.log(paths.map(modifyPath));
```

Or you could use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const paths = [
  "/data/path/one",
  "data/path/two",
];
const modifyPath = p => {
  return p.replace(/\/?data(.*)/, '$1');
}
console.log(paths.map(modifyPath));
```

Comment: Have in mind if `data` isn't present in the path this will yield undefined.